# Web User Control Throwing Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webusercontrol

I am having a problem with my web user control (WUC).  Whenever the page tries to it load, the browser gets a javascript error: "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  This is occurring because my WUC is trying to execute some jquery before my scriptmanager on my master page is referenced.

First, my WUC is a menu bar that every web page will have.  I am actually referencing a dll file to create my user control, which it seems to use jquery to build the menu bar.  In order for the jquery to work, it needs to reference jquery-1.11.3.  Now, as I mentioned, I have a master page that has a scriptmanager, and I am properly referencing jquery-1.11.3 in it.  Also, just to clarify, my scriptmanager is the first tag in my form tag.

Now, the only way I can seem to get my WUC to load properly is by referencing jquery-1.11.3 in the header contentplaceholder for each page specifically.  This is very redundant, and something I want to avoid.  Does anyone know how to solve this issue?